# Need help in generating rows in database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, schema

I have a table in my database like this

```
HatID   HatName    HatPrice     LowestStock     HighestStock     Count
________________________________________________________________________

ERA      New Era     $25.99        1               5              -
STA      Starter     $20           1               5              -
```

However, I want to achieve a table like this,

```
HatID           HatName    HatPrice   LowestStock  HighestStock   Count
________________________________________________________________________

ERA000001       New Era     $25.99        1               5        1

ERA000002       New Era     $25.99        1               5        2

ERA000003       New Era     $25.99        1               5        3 

ERA000004       New Era     $25.99        1               5        4

ERA000005       New Era     $25.99        1               5        5 

STA000001       Starter     $20           1               5        1

STA000002       Starter     $20           1               5        2 

STA000003       Starter     $20           1               5        3 

STA000004       Starter     $20           1               5        4 

STA000005       Starter     $20           1               5        5
```

I am aware that you can't code this in the SQL Schema, but I am curious as to how I would do it in Java

How would I code this in Java?

The reason why I want a table like the latter so that after I make a sale, I can remove the HatID related to that purchase.

Comment: based on the highest stock number you want the row to be repeated

Comment: @NidhishKrishnan yes, I want to generate all the records between the lowestStock and highestStock

Comment: Why you want to do this - I mean generate count between lowest stock and highest stock. Removing one record after selling will have no sence. If you use partition of your stock you should use some special characteristic for each hat - for example number of party (ERA000001) where count will be - amount of hats in current party. When one of hats will be sale you need to decrese count in current party and so on.

Comment: @MikkaRin how do I implement this? I am so so so so confused :S.
I am new to all of this

Comment: hey say if you have a table named TableA having the first two rows of data.....you mean you want another TableB with the same schema structure into which you want all those counted values shown

Comment: @NidhishKrishnan I want to know how to code that. Wow I am so useless, I give up now. Ideally I wanted someone to help me out with the coding not give me advice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a number table and join with the source table.It s better to create number table with 100 numbers

```
create table numbers(number);
insert into numbers
select 1 union all select 2 union all
select 3 union all select 4 union all
select 5;


select 
    t1.HatID   , t1.HatName    ,t1.HatPrice     ,t1.LowestStock     
   ,t1.HighestStock     
   ,t2.number
from 
    your_table as t1 inner join numbers as t2 
    on t2.number>=t1.LowestStock and t2.number<=t1.HighestStock;
```

Comment: I don't understand your code. Sorry. I tried it in SQL Fiddle and I am getting errors. Also where do I write this code? In Java? SQL?

Comment: You should try this in SQL. Also change your_table into actual table name

Comment: What about the create table numbers(number)?? Why do I even need that table? If so what is the primary key? What is select 1, select 2? I would appreciate it if you could write one for my example please. It means a lot

Comment: Also, you code only selects up to 5 numbers, and it doesn't create a composite key... I am lost now. I am useless :(

Comment: numbers table is a one-time creation table. You just need that table to join with your original table to produce multiple rows. It creates a table with five rows with numbers from 1 to 5

Comment: But I don't won't to create a table with five rows. I want it to create rows from a given range between LowestStock and HighestStock. So if I input 1, as my lowest stock and 50, as my highest stock, in my Java program it should produce 50 records. How do I code that? That is the tough question

Comment: Did you actually execute the code and see what it returns? As I said in my post, create a table with 100 numbers to handle large numbers

Comment: Yeah I tried it in Fiddle. Only produces up to 5 numbers. Not 10 or even 5 for that matter! Check it out on Fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e524e/1/0)

Comment: What I am saying is that the numbers table should have more rows say 100 numbers. I have just given an example with five numbers. Expand it for 100 numbers and try my code

Comment: Sorry it doesn't answer my question at all. Never mind. I wanted it to produce all the records in a given range. Look at the example I provided at the top. I want it automatically generate numbers. Forget it man.

Answer (score -1):

To do this there are two ways that you can adopt:

1. Insert data manually.
2. Write a method in java which will take all these parameters and will insert in table using `Insert Into` SQl Query. Thus, you will not have to write multiple Insertion Queries.

Comment: Hi,yes I want to write it in Java, but I have no clue as to how to do it :(. I am new to all of this programming and I am trying to learn as I am interested.